# Missing Siverlight templates in Visual Studio 2008

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2008, silverlight

I have Visual Studio 2008 (sp1, .NET 3.5).
I have installed Silverlight 3 SDK and Silverlight 4 SDK beta + Sivelrlight toolkit.
I also have installed Windows Phone Developer Tools CTP that includes Visual Studio 2010 Express for Windows Phone CTP.

I have noticed that when i start a new project in VS2008 all the Silverlight templates are missing.

Any tip how to get them?

Thanx !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sliverlight 4 integrates with Visual Studio 2010. You can currently get the Release Candiate of VS 2010.

Comment: thanx Malcom, but i was missing templates for SL 3 in VS08.
But then again, the problem was because i was too sloppy.

I did not install:

http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/confirmation.aspx?familyId=9442b0f2-7465-417a-88f3-5e7b5409e9dd&displayLang=en

Works now.

Comment: ah - I misunderstood the question. I thought it was the SL 4 templates that you were not seeing.